# Calculate n'th power of a (diagonalizable + nilpotent) matrix

Tags: matrices

I have $A=\begin{bmatrix} 4&2\\-2&0\end{bmatrix}$ and I had to show that $A=N+D$ where $N$ is nilpotent and $D$ is diagonalizable.

I then found $N=\begin{bmatrix} 2&2\\-2&-2\end{bmatrix}$ and $D=\begin{bmatrix} 2&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$ which is diagonal (and diagonalizable).

I now need to give an expression for $A^{n}$ and have no clue where what to do. Can I get a hint?

Comment: $N$ and $D$ commute because $D = 2 I$. So you can use the usual binomial expansion and that $N^2 = 0$ to find $A^n = (N + D)^n$. Note that $D^n$ is quite easy to find because $D$ is diagonal!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that diagonal matrix $\;D\;$ is way more than merely diagonal: it is a scalar matrix, since $\;D=2I\;$ , and thus it commutes with **all** square matrices $\;2\times2\;$, and thus you can apply Newton's binomial theorem:

$$A^n=\left(N+D\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk N^nD^{n-k}$$

...and now you could use what yuou know about $\;N,\,D\;$ ...

Comment: Might be a dumb question but do we have to know that two matrices $A,B$ commute in order to apply Newton's binomial to $(A+B)^{n}$?

Comment: @Pilpel Of course, ottherwise it fails spectacularly. For example, $\;A+B)^2\;$ becomes $$(A+B)^2=(A+B)(A+B)=A^2+AB+BA+B^2...$$ Remember that the formula of Newton applies *because* we can gather together similar terms, which are all the produycts **no matter their order** .Here, that order matters if the matrices don't commute.

Comment: @Pilpel In this case one of the matrices is a multiple of the identity, so they do commute.